# Calculating the powers of a vector elementwise

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave, exponentiation, elementwise-operations

I have a vector `[x, y, ...]` in Octave and I would like to take the pth powers of the elements to get the new vector `[x^p, y^p, ...]`. Anybody has an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
v = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
p = 2;
w = v.^p;
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/qZasVA)):

```
1    2    3    4    5
1    4    9   16   25
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to apply an operation element wise to a vector/matrix, prepend the operator with a dot:

```
b=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
b2=b.^2;
```